# Some outpost result using two condition

Tags: xslt

I have to transform xml file where i should check field id '0', field id '1' and sum field id '2'. For example I have:

```
<document>
    <line id="0">
        <field id="0">MAR</field>
        <field id="1">doc1</field>
        <field id="2">2</field>
    </line>
    <line id="1">
        <field id="0">MAR</field>
        <field id="1">doc2</field>
        <field id="2">3</field>
    </line>
    <line id="2">
        <field id="0">AAA></field>
        <field id="1">doc4</field>
    </line>
    <line id="3">
        <field id="0">MAR</field>
        <field id="1">doc1</field>
        <field id="2">4</field>
    </line>
</document>
```

result should be:

```
<type-MAR>
    <document>doc1</document>
    <sum>6</sum>
    </type-MAR>   
<type-MAR>
    <document>doc2</document>
    <sum>3</sum>
</type-MAR>
```

there I should take all MAR lines, and show some results which are depends of field id '1'.

My idea was, first off all do cycle(for each) and use condition(when). Maybe somebody offer more omptimal decision.

I add new note, how to check if data comes like that:

```
<field id="0">MAR999</field>
<field id="1">doc1-1231</field>
```

First field i try to use function contains 'MAR', others substring-before '-'. but I stuck when I try it use on Yours program. maybe you can take some advice for it?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete ans easy XSLT solution that uses the Muenchian method for grouping. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kLineById0Id1" match="line[field[@id=2]]"
  use="concat(field[@id=0],'+',field[@id=1])"/>

 <xsl:template match=
  "line[field[@id=2]
      and
        generate-id()
       =
        generate-id(key('kLineById0Id1',
                        concat(field[@id=0],
                               '+',field[@id=1])
                       )[1])
       ]
  ">
  <xsl:element name="type-{field[@id=0]}">
       <document>
        <xsl:value-of select="field[@id=1]"/>
       </document>
       <sum>
        <xsl:value-of select=
        "sum(key('kLineById0Id1',
                concat(field[@id=0],
                       '+',field[@id=1])
               )
               /field[@id=2]
           )
        "/>
       </sum>
     </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<document>
    <line id="0">
        <field id="0">MAR</field>
        <field id="1">doc1</field>
        <field id="2">2</field>
    </line>
    <line id="1">
        <field id="0">MAR</field>
        <field id="1">doc2</field>
        <field id="2">3</field>
    </line>
    <line id="2">
        <field id="0">AAA></field>
        <field id="1">doc4</field>
    </line>
    <line id="3">
        <field id="0">MAR</field>
        <field id="1">doc1</field>
        <field id="2">4</field>
    </line>
</document>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<type-MAR>
   <document>doc1</document>
   <sum>6</sum>
</type-MAR>
<type-MAR>
   <document>doc2</document>
   <sum>3</sum>
</type-MAR>
```

**Explanation**: The **[Muenchian method for grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)** is used with the key defined as the concatenation of two elements.

Comment: +1. Beat me for seconds :) Though I used consecutive predicates and push-style instead of concatenaded key.

Comment: @Flack: Actually my solution does a little-bit more than the OP asks, but in this case produces what he wants. :)

Comment: @Petras: I always test my answers before posting them. I just copy and paste the results. The only way you may not get the same results is if you modified my solution, if you applied it on different XML document or if you are using a non-compliant XSLT processor. Also, saying "it does not work" has exactly 0 bits information value.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev: when i try to do transformation, my XMLSpy turn off. Now I try, on another program(cooktop) it's work. I don't know how it's happen... Sorry.

Comment: @Petras: Maybe you have a very old version of Altova. I am using AltovaXML2011 and with it I get exactly the same correct result as with other XSLT processors.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev: now is working ok. I'm using 2008rel2.v.2. i just turn off processes which don't take to work correctly for altova.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev:can you please see this post and give some suggestion for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474971/how-to-fetch-the-other-tags-by-targeting-a-particular-tag

Answer (score 2):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="kLine" match="line" use="field[@id='1']"/>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <r>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="line
                [field[@id='0'] = 'MAR']
                [count(
                    . | key('kLine', field[@id='1'])[1]
                    ) = 1]
                "/>
        </r>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="line">
        <type-MAR>
            <document>
                <xsl:value-of select="field[@id='1']"/>
            </document>
            <sum>
                <xsl:value-of select="
                    sum(
                        key('kLine', field[@id='1'])/
                        field[@id='2']
                        )"/>
            </sum>
        </type-MAR>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Correct against your sample will be:

```
<r>
    <type-MAR>
        <document>doc1</document>
        <sum>6</sum>
    </type-MAR>
    <type-MAR>
        <document>doc2</document>
        <sum>3</sum>
    </type-MAR>
</r>
```

Comment: sposiba za otvet. eta mnie prigoditsa :)

Comment: +1 for a correct answer and for editing the question, while I was typing the answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="kLineById0-Id1" match="line"
             use="concat(field[@id='0'],'+',field[@id='1'])"/>
    <xsl:param name="pId0" select="'MAR'"/>
    <xsl:template match="document">
        <result>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="line[generate-id()=
                                              generate-id(
                                                 key('kLineById0-Id1',
                                                     concat($pId0,
                                                            '+',
                                                            field[@id='1']
                                                     )
                                                 )[1]
                                              )]"/>
        </result>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="line">
        <xsl:element name="type-{$pId0}">
            <document>
                <xsl:value-of select="field[@id='1']"/>
            </document>
            <sum>
                <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('kLineById0-Id1',
                                              concat(field[@id='0'],
                                                     '+',
                                                     field[@id='1']
                                              )
                                          )/field[@id='2']
                                      )"/>
            </sum>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<result>
    <type-MAR>
        <document>doc1</document>
        <sum>6</sum>
    </type-MAR>
    <type-MAR>
        <document>doc2</document>
        <sum>3</sum>
    </type-MAR>
</result>
```

**Note**: Grouping by both `@id` attributes, sum group, dynamic element name, parameterized first @id.

Comment: @Alejandro: The OP wants grouping only when the first key is "MAR". Therefore, you can use a single-keyd solution as @Flack. If you really want two-key solution, then the name of the generated element shouldn't be static. Have a look at my solution. :)

Comment: @Dimitre: Both @id are the key. It doesn't matter that you output **all the groups** as in your answer, or **just some parameterized groups** like in mine. With a one only @id key you need to filter, making the solution not optimal.

Comment: Thanks Alejandro! yours decision is also useful for me.

Comment: @Alejandro: Glad to see that based on my comment you corrected the generated literal-result element to a dynamically generated one. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answers, I use Flack decision and make some correction:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="kLine" match="line" use="substring(field[@id='1'],1,4)"/>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <document>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="line[contains(field[@id='0'], 'MAR')][count(. | key('kLine', substring(field[@id='1'],1,4))[1]) = 1]"/>
        </document>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="line">
        <type-MAR>
            <document>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring(field[@id='1'],1,4)"/>
            </document>
            <sum>
                <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('kLine', substring(field[@id='1'],1,4))/field[@id='2'])"/>
            </sum>
        </type-MAR>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Dimitre and Alejandro decisions are also good and useful(maybe more professional). But Dimitre more concentrate on my task which I wrote, for example he use condition to check if we have the second field(I didn't wrote that not only MAR could have field2). Alejandro to check it use parameter, so for me it was a good lesson to search more information how to use it, because with xsl language I have less than one month experience. So for me was difficult to prepair Yours programs for my work. Flack text was more understandable for me as a beginner.