# how to fetch the other tags by targeting a particular tag

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Here I have pasted a sample of XML that was tag names like `21A,50F,21D,22B`.

Normally if I need to fetch a particular tag,  I can use logic below easily in XSLT:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="tag[name = '21A'] ">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="substring(tag[name = '21A']/value,1,1) = '/'">
                <xsl:variable name="result" select="concat(translate(tag[name = '21A']/value,',',' '),'&#13;')"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring(substring-before(substring-after($result,'&#13;'),'&#13;'),1,11)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="substring(tag[name = '21A']/value,1,1) != '/'">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring(tag[name = '21A']/value,1,11)"/>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

but here I have a requirement as `Sequence A` and `Sequence B`.

- the tags which populated above `50F` come under `sequence A`
- the tags which populated below `50F` come under `sequence B`

since we need to fetch the tags based on using `50F` tag. Can any one please give a suggestion?

```
<local>
    <message>
        <block4>
            <tag>
                <name>21A</name>
                <value>ALW1031</value>
            </tag>
            <tag>
                <name>50F</name>
                <value>TESTING CITI BANK EFT9</value>
            </tag>
            <tag>
                <name>21D</name>
                <value>OUR</value>
            </tag>
            <tag>
                <name>22B</name>
                <value>ipubby</value>
            </tag>
        </block4>
    </message>
</local>
```

output required:

```
ALW1031,OUR
```

Previously if suppose they have populate `21A` two times means I have used the position as [1] and [2] as while calling tag values. Now they will populate 21 tag repeatedly but tags may be `A` or `D` so I need to target `50f` tag blindly. Whatever tag they will provide, either `A` or `D` before `50F` I need to fetch similarly whatever they populate tags after `50F` we able to fetch so avoiding positions.

---

**Summary**:
*@Treemonkey*: hope you had a glance of my sample XML. It has some tag like `21A,50F` and so on. Assume if I have two fields `field1,field2` earlier they have populated tags as same repeated tags as `21A` at that time I have fetched as `21A` having beside by marking position [1] for field 1 (`tag[name = '21A'][1]`)

Similarly `21A` having beside by marking position [2] for field 2, now they will populate `21` but tags were different as `A` or `D`. As I have said `field1` should concentrate `sequence A` and `field2` should concentrate as `sequence B` so now we should not bother about positions for fetch we have a demarcation like tag `50F` whatever fields will populate before `50F` has to treated as `sequence A` and after `50F` has to be treated as `sequence B`.

So finally we need to write as XSLT by targeting `50`F. If I want to display `21A` field in (sample XML)  which before `50F` so we need write a logic in XSLT as select tag `21A`  before `50F` tag for to produce data in field 1 and for field 2 we need to fetch as `21D` after `50F` so we need to write a logic as select `21D` after `50F`.

Comment: @_pravz: what should be the result of the transformation? Please, provide.

Comment: @pravs might need to reword your question it is difficult to understand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirements aren't exactly clear, but the following expressions should help.

Select all siblings before the `tag` whose child `name` has a particular value:

```
/*/*/*/tag[name='50F']/preceding-sibling::*
```

Select following siblings:

```
/*/*/*/tag[name='50F']/following-sibling::*
```

Select just the immediately preceding element:

```
/*/*/*/tag[name='50F']/preceding-sibling::*[1]
```

Select preceding siblings having a child `name` with a particular value:

```
/*/*/*/tag[name='50F']/preceding-sibling::*[name='21A']
```

Select following siblings having a child `name` with a particular value:

```
/*/*/*/tag[name='50F']/following-sibling::*[name='21D']
```